# Cancelling Coroutine when Home button presseddown or returned main menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, countdown, coroutine

some pretext of what I am doing ; I am currently locking down my skill buttons via setting interactable = false in coroutines. Showing text of remaning seconds via textmeshpro and setting them deactive when countdown is over. But I am having problem when home button is pressed/ returned main menu. I would like to refresh my buttons cooldowns and stop coroutines when its pressed. But it is staying in lock position.

this is my cooldown coroutine

```
static List<CancellationToken> cancelTokens = new List<CancellationToken>();

...

public IEnumerator StartCountdown(float countdownValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            this.currentCooldownDuration = countdownValue;
            // Deactivate myButton
            this.myButton.interactable = false;
            //activate text to show remaining cooldown seconds
            this.m_Text.SetActive(true);
            while (this.currentCooldownDuration > 0 && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                this.m_Text.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = this.currentCooldownDuration.ToString(); //Showing the Score on the Canvas
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
                this.currentCooldownDuration--;

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // deactivate text and Reactivate myButton
            // deactivate text
            this.m_Text.SetActive(false);
            // Reactivate myButton
            this.myButton.interactable = true;
        }

    }
```

```
static public void cancelAllCoroutines()
   {
       Debug.Log("cancelling all coroutines with total of : " + cancelTokens.Count);
       foreach (CancellationToken ca in cancelTokens)
       {
           ca.IsCancellationRequested = true;
       }
   }
```

```
void OnButtonClick()
    {

    CancellationToken cancelToken = new CancellationToken();
        cancelTokens.Add(cancelToken);

        Coroutine co;
        co = StartCoroutine(StartCountdown(cooldownDuration, cancelToken));
        myCoroutines.Add(co);

    }
```

this is where I catch when home button pressed/returned main menu. when catch it and pop pauseMenu

```
public void PauseGame()
    {
        GameObject menu = Instantiate(PauseMenu);
        menu.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, false);
        gameManager.PauseGame();
        EventManager.StartListening("ReturnMainMenu", (e) =>
        {
            Cooldown.cancelAllCoroutines();
            Destroy(menu);
            BackToMainMenu();
            EventManager.StopListening("ReturnMainMenu");
        });
        ...
```

I also stop time when game on the pause

```
public void PauseGame() {
        Time.timeScale = 0.0001f;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `CancellationToken` incorrectly in this case. `CancellationToken` is a struct that wraps a `CancellationTokenSource` like this:

```
public bool IsCancellationRequested 
{
    get
    {
        return source != null && source.IsCancellationRequested;
    }
}
```

Because it's a struct, it gets passed around *by value*, meaning the one you store in your list is **not the same** instance as the one that your `Coroutine` has.

The typical way to handle cancellation is to create a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.8) and pass its `Token` around. Whenever you want to cancel it, you simply call the `.Cancel()` method on the `CancellationTokenSource`. The reason for it being this way is so that the `CancellationToken` can **only** be cancelled through the 'source' reference and not by consumers of the token.

In your case, you are creating a token with no source at all so I would suggest making the following changes:

First of all, change your `cancelTokens` list to be a:

```
List<CancellationTokenSource>
```

Next, change your `OnButtonClick()` method to look like this:

```
public void OnButtonClick()
{
    // You should probably call `cancelAllCoroutines()` here  
    cancelAllCoroutines();

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancelTokens.Add(cancellationTokenSource);
    Coroutine co = StartCoroutine(StartCountdown(cooldownDuration, cancellationTokenSource.Token));
    myCoroutines.Add(co);
}
```

And lastly, change your `cancelAllCoroutines()` method to this:

```
public static void CancelAllCoroutines()
{
   Debug.Log("cancelling all coroutines with total of : " + cancelTokens.Count);
   foreach (CancellationTokenSource ca in cancelTokens)
   {
       ca.Cancel();
   }

   // Clear the list as @Jack Mariani mentioned
   cancelTokens.Clear();
}
```

I would suggest reading the docs on [Cancellation Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8) or alternatively, as @JLum suggested, use the [StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) method that Unity provides.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that it is recommended that `CancallationTokenSources` be disposed of when no longer in use so as to ensure no memory leaks occur. I would recommend doing this in an [OnDestroy()](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html#WhenTheObjectIsDestroyed) hook for your `MonoBehaviour` like so:

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    foreach(var source in cancelTokens)
    {
        source.Dispose();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
As @Jack Mariani mentioned in his answer, multiple `CancellationTokenSources` is overkill in this case. All it would really allow you to do is have more fine-grained control over which `Coroutine` gets cancelled. In this case, you are cancelling them all in one go, so yeah, an optimisation would be to only create one of them. There are multiple optimisations that could be made here, but they are beyond the scope of this question. I did not include them because I felt like it would bloat this answer out more than necessary.

However, I would argue his point about `CancellationToken` being 'mostly intended for Task'. Pulled straight from the first couple of lines in the MSDN [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the .NET Framework uses a unified model for cooperative cancellation of asynchronous or **long-running synchronous operations**. This model is based on a **lightweight object** called a cancellation token

`CancellationTokens` are lightweight objects. For the most part, they are just simple `Structs` that reference a `CancellationTokenSource`. The 'overhead' that is mentioned in his answer is negligible and, in my eyes, totally worth it when considering readability and intention.

You *could* pass a load of `booleans` around with indices or subscribe to events using `string` literals and those approaches would work.
But at what cost? Confusing and difficult-to-read code? I would say not worth it.

The choice is ultimately yours though.

Answer (score 1):

### MAIN ISSUE

In your question you just use the bool `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` and no other functionalities of Cancellation Token.

So, following the logic of your method, you might just want to have a `List<bool> cancellationRequests` and pass them using [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

Still, I would not go ahead with that logic nor with the logic proposed by Darren Ruane, because **they have one main flaw**.

**FLAW** => these solutions keep adding things to 2 lists `cancelTokens.Add(...)` and  `myCoroutines.Add(co)`, without ever clearing them.

---

```
public void OnButtonClick()
{
    ...other code
    //this never get cleared
    cancelTokens.Add(cancelToken);
    ...other code
    //this never get cleared
    myCoroutines.Add(co);
}
```

If you want to go down this way you could remove them manually, but it's tricky, because you never know when they will be required (the Coroutine can be called many frames after `CancelAllCoroutines` method).

---

### SOLUTION

**Use a static event instead of a list**

To remove the list and make the class even more decoupled you might use a static event, created and invoked in the script where you call the `PauseGame` method.

```
//the event somewhere in the script
public static event Action OnCancelCooldowns;

public void PauseGame()
{
    ...your code here, with no changes...
    EventManager.StartListening("ReturnMainMenu", (e) =>
    {
        //---> Removed ->Cooldown.cancelAllCoroutines();
        //replaced by the event
        OnCancelCooldowns?.Invoke();

        ...your code here, with no changes...
    });
    ...
```

You will listen to the static event in your coroutine.

```
public IEnumerator StartCountdown(float countdownValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        bool wantToStop = false;
        //change YourGameManager with the name of the script with your PauseGame method.
        YourGameManager.OnCancelCooldowns += () => wantToStop = true;

        ...your code here, with no changes...

        while (this.currentCooldownDuration > 0 && !wantToStop)
        {
            ...your code here, with no changes...
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ...your code here, with no changes...
    }
}
```

---

### EASIER SOLUTION

Or you might just stay simple and use [MEC Coroutines](http://trinary.tech/category/mec/) instead of Unity ones (they are also more [performant](http://trinary.tech/category/mec/) ).

[MEC Free](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/more-effective-coroutines-free-54975) offers the tag functionality that solves the problem entirely.

**SINGLE COROUTINE START**

```
void OnButtonClick() => Timing.RunCoroutine(CooldownCoroutine, "CooldownTag");
```

**STOP ALL COROUTINE** with a specific tag

```
public void PauseGame()
{
    ...your code here, with no changes...
    EventManager.StartListening("ReturnMainMenu", (e) =>
    {
        //---> Removed ->Cooldown.cancelAllCoroutines();
        //replaced by this
        Timing.KillCoroutines("CooldownTag");

        ...your code here, with no changes...
    });
    ...
```

Further [notes on tags](http://trinary.tech/layers-and-tags/) (please consider that MEC free has only tags and not layers, but you require just tags in your use case).

EDIT:
*After some thought I just decided to remove the details of the bool solution, it might confuse the answer and it was going beyond the scope of this question.*

Comment: "CancellationToken are mostly intended for Task" - The MSDN [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) say they are intended for "asynchronous or **long-running synchronous operations**". "You do not require the overhead of CancellationToken" - What overhead? They are intended to be extremely lightweight. Have you actually done a profile of their performance and found an 'overhead'? Your suggested solutions are reasonable but I would argue far less readable.

Comment: From the code I read we just require one bool. The cancellation token has surely more overhead than a bool. Further note Task and Coroutines are different. I tend to agree from [this forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/coroutine-vs-async-method.483746/): "_Coroutines are useful for executing methods over a number of frames. Async methods are useful for executing methods after a given task has finished._" Anyway, if you want to use CancellationToken I would not create a list of CancellationTokenSource, but a set of CancellationToken connected to just one source.

Comment: Of course it has more overhead than a bool. But it also has far more readability and intention behind it. The 'overhead' is so negligible that I would argue it is not even worth mentioning. I *know* that Task and Coroutine are different and I don't think I said anything to make you think otherwise. I was just pointing out that "CancellationToken are mostly intended for Task" is just not true. Yes I agree that in the OP's case, a list of them is overkill, I did edit my answer to include that.

Comment: I agree with you on my solution 1, but I think that also your solution (and even the question in itself) have readability issue. Still that is not my main concern. Their biggest issue is that all of them have do not clear the list, that is a memory leak. So I added solution 2 and Solution X as better versions.

Comment: Yes I agree that is a big issue, well spotted on that one.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Darren Ruane. I've just updated the answer to make sure that the old Solution 1 would not be confused as a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has `StopCoroutine()` specifically for ending Coroutines early.

You will want to create a function that you can call on every skill button object when you want to reset them all like this:

```cs
void resetButton()
{
    StopCoroutine(StartCountdown);
    this.currentCooldownDuration = 0;
    this.m_Text.SetActive(false);
    this.myButton.interactable = true;
}
```

Comment: my coroutines include more than skills which I might want them run. So StopCoroutine does not work well for me in this case.